# Rails not giving a destroy_path for resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, routes, resources

using 
Rails 5.1.4 &
ruby 2.4.1

Wondering why Rails would not give a destroy_visitor_path for DELETE request. Any info would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'contents#index'

  resources :contents
  resources :visitors
end
```

Routes:

```
            visitors GET    /visitors(.:format)          visitors#index
                     POST   /visitors(.:format)          visitors#create
         new_visitor GET    /visitors/new(.:format)      visitors#new
        edit_visitor GET    /visitors/:id/edit(.:format) visitors#edit
             visitor GET    /visitors/:id(.:format)      visitors#show
                     PATCH  /visitors/:id(.:format)      visitors#update
                     PUT    /visitors/:id(.:format)      visitors#update
                     DELETE /visitors/:id(.:format)      visitors#destroy
```

Answer (score 2):

Same reason why there's no `update_visitor_path` — it's a singular resource that simply responds to a different HTTP verb.

In your view, you'd `link_to "Delete", visitor_path, method: :delete`

I can't comment on the philosophy behind the design decision, or any of the arguments about whatever spec it's designed to because that's for people who are smarter than I am.

More info on the Rails routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many incidents to delete
It's let you set your own routes:
For example you want to logout after delete (usually in sessions)

```
get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
```